# Why won't components included with the animation rigging package act a components?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I try to use any component included with the animation rigging package in code it acts as if I'm using something none existent.

e.g.  if I use something like

```
private RigBuilder rigBuilder;
```

...it will put a red squiggly line under `RigBuilder` and say:

> The type or namespace name 'RigBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Did you add according namespace? It is part of `UnityEngine.Animations` ... If your project uses Assembly definitions you also still need to reference he according assembly

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following namespace.

```
using UnityEngine.Animations.Rigging;
```